# VB.Net DataAdapter Select String

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, dataadapter

I have a routine to pull data from my database (nothing fancy). I want it to pull rows in which the "StartDate" column is some date in the future. The code below pulls all the rows instead of just the future ones.

I know it must be something silly that I'm doing but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance,
Craig

CODE:

```
Printda = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblShows WHERE StartDate > " & Format(Now, "Short Date"), cn)
```

Updated Code:

```
Printda = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblShows WHERE StartDate > '" & Now.ToString("Short Date") & "'", cn)
```

## Corrected Code:

```
Printda = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblShows WHERE StartDate > Now()", cn)
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter What do you mean by rdbms?

Comment: Have you tried to google it? ;) SQL-Server, MySql or oracle are rdbms. `DateTime` functions are different. But you should do that in the database, for example (T-SQL): `SELECT * FROM tblShows WHERE StartDate > GetDate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblShows WHERE StartDate > #" & Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

In SQL Server this is the default date format. In Oracle is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Use the format that fit your needs, or use parameters if you don't want to care about formatting and give your querys security.

Or you could simply use proper function to get the actual date:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblShows WHERE StartDate > now()"
```

Comment: I have changed my code (see above) but it still throws a data mismatch exception.

Comment: `Now.ToString("Short Date")` is incorrect. Try my answer instead.

Comment: The code is for a VB.Net project using a MS Access database not SQL Server. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The use the function `now()` instead of `getdate()`, and SQL date format or access date format: `#mm/dd/yyyy#`

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Could you update your answer so I can mark the question solved.